# Parameter suggested from documentation not accepted - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, typeerror

I am comparing dataframes with pandas. I want to distinguish the compared dataframe columns by naming them, therefore I'm using the parameter *result_names* from pandas documentation but it returns: *'TypeError: DataFrame.compare() got an unexpected keyword argument 'result_names''*.

Here is the code, that is simply the suggested one in the documentation: (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"],
        "col2": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, np.nan, 5.0],
        "col3": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
    },
    columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"],
)

df2 = df.copy()
df2.loc[0, 'col1'] = 'c'
df2.loc[2, 'col3'] = 4.0

df.compare(df2, result_names=("left", "right"))
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: "Any ideas why?" - you're using an older version of pandas? As noted in the docs you link to, `result_names` is new as of version 1.5.0.

Comment: Yeah that parameter was added in the newest pandas version (1.5.0), so you're almost certainly using an older version.

Comment: What should I do to get the latest version?

Comment: `pip install -U pandas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need pandas **≥1.5**.

For earlier versions, you can instead [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the level:

```
df.compare(df2).rename({'self': 'left', 'other': 'right'}, axis=1, level=1)
```

output:

```
  col1       col3      
  left right left right
0    a     c  NaN   NaN
2  NaN   NaN  3.0   4.0
```